# Android Sorting ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have several `ArrayLists` that are going into the `ListView` adapter. What I'm trying to do is sort by just one of those `ArrayLists`...

```
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    locations = new ArrayList<String>();
    timedates = new ArrayList<String>();

    //arraylists populated here

    adapter = new HomeAdapter(getActivity(), names, locations, timedates);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

How would I go about sorting the entire `ListView` by `timedates` for example?

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Please paste code of sorting that you've tried. also give reference of sorting, how you want.

Comment: try to create model class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a datamodel with only one ArryList. Details are given bellow:

```
arrayList= new ArrayList<DataModel>();

//arraylists populated here

adapter = new HomeAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

DataModel class will look like this:

```
public class DataModel {

    public String names;
    public String locations;
    public String timedates;

}
```

Finally sorting:

```
Collections.sort(arrayList, new SortList());

public class SortList implements Comparator<DataModel> {
    public int compare(DataModel arg0, DataModel arg1) {
        int flag = arg0.timedates.compareTo(arg1.timedates);
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Edit 1:

To add data into the list:

```
DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();
dataModel.names = "Ashiq";
dataModel.locations = "Khulna, Bangladesh";
dataModel.timedates = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

arrayList.add(dataModel);
```

You don't have to use arraylist individually for each item. Just wrap all strings into dataModel and add it to the arraylist for adding each set of data.

Let me know if anything not seem to be clear.

Comment: How would I go about adding my current `ArrayLists` to that class? Thanks!

Comment: Seems pretty clear now. One thing though: how would I get data from the list items for use in the listview adapter? For example, if I wanted to pull dataModel.name for a certain position. Thanks!

Comment: DataModel dataModel = (DataModel)arrayList.get(position);
String name = dataModel.names;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Collections.sort(timedates,new Comparator<String>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2){
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
});
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Doesn't that sort JUST that arraylist? Looking to sort the whole listview based on `timedates`

Comment: what you need to do is create a class with name,location and timedates as fields. Create an arraylist of that class and then use the sort method.

Comment: @zngb that does sort the arraylist but on using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` the data in listview is sorted.